# find the largest and smallest value in a column that corresponds with another column

Tags: awk

I have a 5 column, 10,000+ row CSV data file. I need to find the largest and smallest value from column 2, for each different value in column 1, and then write those to a new file. I am relatively new to grep, awk, head, tail, and the others alike. Here is a few lines of the file in what we can call temp.csv

```
1553 1806.345000 20130516-044310 33.800000 -97.110000 

1555 2106.947000 20130516-044310 33.470000 -94.620000

1559 2106.947000 20130516-044310 31.460000 -97.260000

1573 1807.591000 20130516-045311 41.150000 -94.020000

1573 2107.911000 20130516-045311 41.120000 -94.020000

1573 2408.994000 20130516-045311 41.120000 -94.050000

1573 2709.545000 20130516-045311 41.090000 -94.020000

1573 3010.308000 20130516-045311 41.090000 -94.020000

1573 3310.988000 20130516-045311 41.090000 -93.990000

1573 3611.129000 20130516-045311 41.120000 -93.960000

1573 3912.392000 20130516-045311 41.090000 -93.960000

1585 1806.756000 20130516-045812 31.040000 -98.880000

1585 2107.839000 20130516-045812 31.040000 -98.850000

1585 2408.390000 20130516-045812 31.010000 -98.820000

1585 2709.153000 20130516-045812 31.010000 -98.790000

1611 1804.813000 20130516-051316 31.280000 -97.800000
```

So for example from these data, I would want the output to look like:

```
1553 1806.345000 20130516-044310 33.800000 -97.110000 

1555 2106.947000 20130516-044310 33.470000 -94.620000

1559 2106.947000 20130516-044310 31.460000 -97.260000

1573 1807.591000 20130516-045311 41.150000 -94.020000

1573 3912.392000 20130516-045311 41.090000 -93.960000

1585 1806.756000 20130516-045812 31.040000 -98.880000

1585 2709.153000 20130516-045812 31.010000 -98.790000

1611 1804.813000 20130516-051316 31.280000 -97.800000
```

Some numbers in the first row will only have one entry, in which it would obviously be the largest and smallest. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about duplicates? Keep first or last min/max value?

Comment: Yes, would only need one. Thank you

Comment: Do you REALLY have a blank line between each data line in your input? It matters.

Comment: no, ignore the blank lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '!NF { next }
     !a[$1]++ { if (length(p)) print p; print; p = ""; next }
     { p = $0 } END { if (length(p)) print p }' file
```

Output:

```
1553 1806.345000 20130516-044310 33.800000 -97.110000 
1555 2106.947000 20130516-044310 33.470000 -94.620000
1559 2106.947000 20130516-044310 31.460000 -97.260000
1573 1807.591000 20130516-045311 41.150000 -94.020000
1573 3912.392000 20130516-045311 41.090000 -93.960000
1585 1806.756000 20130516-045812 31.040000 -98.880000
1585 2709.153000 20130516-045812 31.010000 -98.790000
1611 1804.813000 20130516-051316 31.280000 -97.800000
```

Comment: Thank you konsolebox, would you mind explaining the code. It works great, would like to understand what it is doing to learn from it

Comment: @user2938093 The solution is based from the assumption that lines are sorted. Every block `x {}` would run for every record (line) found besides the `END`. `!NF { next }` would skip the blocks that follows it if the number of fields is 0. It happens in empty lines. `!a[$1]++` would give true condition if the value in first column is first encountered and would allow `{ if (length(p)) print p; print; p = ""; next }` to execute. The purpose of that block is to print a previous secondary value if there was one, print the current line, reset `p` to empty and skip the next block.

Comment: When all conditions (`!NF` and `!a[$1]++`) are false, `{ p = $0 }` would execute. This would set the second line to print for the current value in the first column. It would keep assigning and would not be printed until the next new value on the first column (i.e. until `!a[$1]++` evaluates to true again) or until the end of file is reached where the `END` block would execute as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of accomplishing the task. It doesn't care if the data is sorted or not:

```
awk '  
$1 in keys {
    map["min",$1] = (keys[$1] < $2 ? map["min",$1] : $0); 
    map["max",$1] = (keys[$1] > $2 ? map["max",$1] : $0);
}
NF {
    keys[$1] = $2;
}
!seen[$1]++ {
    map["min",$1] = $0;
    map["max",$1] = $0;
}
END {
    for (key in keys) {
        if (map["min",key] == map["max",key]) {
            print map["min",key]
        }
        else { 
            print map["min",key]
            print map["max",key]
        }
    }
}' file
1611 1804.813000 20130516-051316 31.280000 -97.800000
1585 1806.756000 20130516-045812 31.040000 -98.880000
1585 2709.153000 20130516-045812 31.010000 -98.790000
1553 1806.345000 20130516-044310 33.800000 -97.110000 
1555 2106.947000 20130516-044310 33.470000 -94.620000
1559 2106.947000 20130516-044310 31.460000 -97.260000
1573 1807.591000 20130516-045311 41.150000 -94.020000
1573 3912.392000 20130516-045311 41.090000 -93.960000
```

Comment: +1 Beautiful, clear, simple, robust... I may have to retire :-).

Comment: Hang on. keys[$1] only ever contains the very first value seen for the given $1 so this will only work if the input is sorted on $2 for every $1. If $2 first has the value of 15 and then 5 and then 10, then the "min" value will be for the line with 10, not the line with 5. You need separate min and max arrays instead of a single keys array. Or just state it requires the input for each $1 to be sorted on $2. At least it doesn't require the $1 values to be sorted nor contiguous.

Comment: @EdMorton See, thats what I meant when I said I still need to learn a lot from you. Included a block to fix that issue. Thanks so much for the great feedback. You're the best! `:)`